# Why are constant price elasticities reported?

Tags: supply-and-demand, elasticity, price, demand

Price elasticity of demand $\mathrm{e_{D,P} = \dfrac{dD}{dP}. \dfrac{P}{Q^*}}$ clearly depends on the levels of price and quantity.

Then why is everywhere (research papers, textbooks etc.)  a constant estimate provided?

Also, doesn't the non-constancy of the price elasticity render the comparative statics $e_{P^*,\alpha} = \dfrac{e_{D,\alpha}}{e_{S,P}- e_{D,P}}$ invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premise of your question is simply false. You state (emphasis mine):

> Price elasticity of demand $\mathrm{e_{D,P} = \dfrac{dD}{dP}. \dfrac{P}{Q^*}}$ **clearly depends on the levels of price and quantity**.

Incorrect. Consider trivial counter example. A perfectly reasonable demand can be given by:

$$ Q  = A p^{-\epsilon} $$

where $Q$ is quantity, $p$ price and $A$ and $\epsilon$ are constant parameters.

Hence the price elasticity of demand $e$  will be given by:

$$e = \frac{dQ}{dp} \cdot \frac{p}{Q} = -\epsilon  A p^{-\epsilon-1} \frac{p}{ A p^{-\epsilon}} = -\epsilon $$

Consequently, **clearly** elasticity **does not** *always* depend on the levels of price and quantity and can be completely constant.

> Then why is everywhere (research papers, textbooks etc.) a constant estimate provided?

Again false premise, in several textbooks and papers you will find elasticity being expressed as a function of price and quantity. Since you made statement about **everywhere** it is enough to show one example to the contrary which would be Varian Microeconomic Analysis, where there are several examples where elasticity in a model won't be constant.

In empirical papers elasticity will be most often estimated as a single number, but this is due to the way how empirical models are set up. It is too broad to discuss all empirical models in a single question, but typically coefficients estimated by model are values that hold on average. For example, in a regression $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 E_i + e_i$ where $y$ would be income and $E$ years of education, the $\beta_1$ would tell us how much on average $y$ increases with education, it would not tell us what happen to every individual kids. That is if $\beta_1=10$ that does not mean that if your kid stays in school one more year they are guaranteed that their income will increase by 10. That is just a value we would expect for average kid.  Similarly, even if researcher assumes elasticity is not constant because they are using linear demand, they might be forced to estimate elasticity at a point rather than as a whole function and convention is to estimate point elasticity at average quantity and price (see discussion in [Espey  Espey  & Shaw (1997)](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1029/97WR00571).